# How to scroll entire activity while scrolling tablayout android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

How do I scroll my entire activity while scrolling my tablayout.?

E.g - when I scroll my tabLayout - the entire activity should scroll...not just the viewpager portion of the tablayout..

**Activity should only scroll when the tablayout is scolled.**

This is what I want...(Notice how the entire activity scrolls....when the tablayout is scrolled)

[image: image1]

This is what I have....(Notice how only the tablayout fragment portion scrolls when the tablayout is scrolled)

[image: image2]

This is what I have tried..as I have read...

**1.** Add ScrollView to the layout activity containing the tablayout

**2**  Add NestedScrollView to the fragment layout.

**photo_activity.xml** - Activity containing the tablayout and viewpager

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/yearTabLayout"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:text="@string/top"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/recent"
                android:text="@string/recent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yearTabLayout"
            android:id="@+id/year_view_pager" />

    </RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

**fragment_photos.xml** - Fragment of the current selected tab in the tablayout.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data class="TopPhotosActivityBinding" />

   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true">

     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshTopPhotos">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/topPhotosRecyclerView"
                tools:listitem="@layout/top_photos_year">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: i don't know the details because i never used it but i think it is something that can be achieved with coordinator layout see how it works -> https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout and https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="300dp"
      >

       <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
           app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="56dp"
           app:expandedTitleMarginStart="40dp"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
           app:title="Hello MindOrks!"
           >

           <!-- Put your top content here -->

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:text="Sample Top Content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:textSize="25dp"
                   android:textColor="@color/white"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           </LinearLayout>


       </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/yearTabLayout"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/black">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/top"
                    android:text="Top"/>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recent"
                    android:text="Recent"/>

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/yearTabLayout"
                android:id="@+id/year_view_pager" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It will look something like this :
[image]

Comment: It works but 2 things..
1. The color of my layout became green color (section where I have a calender icon and text which says "something"...)...how to change it to former color white?..

2. Items(photos) in tablayout are not displaying anymore...I have to set custom height of viewPager to maybe 1000dp before it works......wrap_content or  match_parent doesnt work.

Comment: I have just added it as a reference for you may be your primary color is green that's why it may happened like that. I have kept a comment to add your top section code have you seen it ?

Comment: And for your 2nd problem try to remove NestedScrollView as top layout in fragment_photos.xml   use only RelativeLayout

Comment: I have changed the color to white....but the 2nd problem still there...I have removed the nestedScrollView,...The height of viewPager is the problem. I have to set a custom height before it works,,I need it to be wrap_content.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you are trying actually now

Comment: Its the same code you posted in your answer,....only thing is that my items (photos) in the tablayout aren't displaying anymore...This is as a result of the viewPager2 height....match_parent or wrap_content doesn't seem to work anymore...I have to manaully set the height of the viewPager2 to maybe 800dp before content start showing....I want the height of the viewPager 2 to be either match_parent or wrap_content.

Comment: Works now....I had to set  android:fillViewport="true" in my NestedScrollView...thanks.